# Date Range Tree

Tags: c#, datetime

```
public struct DateRange : IEquatable<DateRange>, IComparable<DateRange>
{
    private readonly DateTime _min;
    private readonly DateTime _max;

    public DateRange(DateTime min, DateTime max)
    {
        if (min.CompareTo(max) > 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("max", "Cannot be less than min.");
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
    }

    public DateTime Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
    }

    public DateTime Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
    }

    public bool Intersects(DateRange other)
    {
        return other.Max >= this.Min && other.Min <= this.Max;
    }

    public bool Contains(DateRange other)
    {
        return other.Min >= this.Min && other.Max <= this.Max;
    }

    public bool Precedes(DateRange other)
    {
        return this.Max < other.Min;
    }

    public bool Follows(DateRange other)
    {
        return this.Min > other.Max;
    }

    public int CompareTo(DateRange other)
    {
        if (Contains(other) || Follows(other))
            return 1;

        if (Precedes(other))
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }

    public bool Equals(DateRange other)
    {
        return this.Min.Equals(other.Min) && this.Max.Equals(other.Max);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is DateRange && Equals((DateRange)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + Min.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Max.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} to {1:yyyy-MM-dd}", Min, Max);
    }
}


public sealed class DateRangeTree : IEnumerable<DateRange>
{
    private readonly IImmutableList<DateRange> _items;
    private readonly DateRangeTreeNode _root;

    public DateRangeTree(IEnumerable<DateRange> items)
    {
        if (items == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
        _items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Min).ThenByDescending(x => x.Max).ToImmutableList();
        _root = new DateRangeTreeNode(_items);
    }

    public IEnumerator<DateRange> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in _root)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private sealed class DateRangeTreeNode : IEnumerable<DateRange>
    {
        private readonly DateRange _center;
        private readonly DateRangeTreeNode _left;
        private readonly DateRangeTreeNode _right;
        private readonly IImmutableList<DateRange> _items;

        public DateRangeTreeNode(IEnumerable<DateRange> items)
        {
            if (items == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

            var points = new System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<DateRange>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                points.Add(item);;
            }
            _center = points.Skip(points.Count / 2).First();

            var ns = new List<DateRange>();
            var ls = new List<DateRange>();
            var rs = new List<DateRange>();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (item.Precedes(_center))
                {
                    ls.Add(item);
                }
                else if (item.Follows(_center))
                {
                    rs.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    ns.Add(item);
                }
            }

            if (ns.Count > 0)
            {
                _items = ns.OrderBy(x => x.Min).ThenByDescending(x => x.Max).ToImmutableList();
            }

            if (ls.Count > 0)
            {
                _left = new DateRangeTreeNode(ls.OrderBy(x => x.Min).ThenByDescending(x => x.Max));
            }

            if (rs.Count > 0)
            {
                _right = new DateRangeTreeNode(rs.OrderBy(x => x.Min).ThenByDescending(x => x.Max));
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<DateRange> GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (_left != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in _left)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
            if (_items.Count > 0)
            {
                yield return _items[0];
            }
            if (_right != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in _right)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a dump of code, which makes this question very unclear, and bordering off-topic. Please see [how to ask a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31503)

Comment: I'm looking for a review of the code as is. If you look through my history you will find many similar questions.

Comment: The difference is that a hash map, Fibonacci heap, immutable singly-linked list, and observable queue are all "classic" problems that programmers often attempt when learning, and could be considered self-explanatory. A Date Range Tree, not so much.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it would've hurt to ask a question or to have some introductory text.  I've reviewed some of your past CR questions and do not agree with you that they are similar in nature to this where code is just shoved in our face.

That said, I see the `DateTimeKind` is completely ignored.  So is it okay if the `Min` has a different kind than the `Max`?  What if both are `Unspecified` since `Unspecified` can mean (1) the time zone is not known, (2) the time zone is inconsequential, or (3) its a time zone for something that is neither Utc nor Local.  Hence, there is an ambiguity with `Unspecified`.

I am in US Central Time.  I can pass a min representing a time from US Eastern, and a max representing a time from US Mountain.  And I could get undesired results.

I have worked with other libraries that have something similar.  These other libs reject `Unspecified` and require `DateTime` inputs that either `Utc` or `Local` in order to remove the ambiguity.

I'm not a fan of the property names Min and Max.  For a date range I tend to think in terms from a starting time to an ending time.  I have a preference for StartTime and EndTime then, but that's me.

Comment: Maybe you're right... I'm gonna try and convince myself to write out some solid prose that sums up the code.